# Make my app appear in the change wallpaper list

Tags: android, android-wallpaper

I am making a wallpaper app, and I want to add my app to the default app list, so when user wants to change his background, my app will appear as option. Can someone please help me out

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SET_WALLPAPER" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

More info here:

> [action.SET_WALLPAPER](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SET_WALLPAPER)

Hope this helps u out.

Comment: Thanks you very much

Comment: @SỹPhạm Glad I could help, did it solve your problem? Than please mark it as answer ;)